# 1-D Interpolation between any number of points

Tags: interpolation

I'm looking for an algorithm which will allow me to calculate outputs for any given input instead of just the few ones I'm given in advance.

The input is a number from interval $0 - 100$ representing a percentage. I'm given a few of the desired outputs in advance; they correspond to inputs evenly distributed along the whole $0 - 100$ range. For example, if I am given three outputs, A, B and C, they correspond to $100$, $50$ and $0$ respectively. If, instead, I am given five of them, they should correspond to inputs of $100$, $75$, $50$, $25$ and $0$. In between these given values, the output should increase or decrease proportionally. For example, in the first example, the output corresponding to 75 should be right in the middle between A and B (since $75$ is right in the middle between $100$ and $50$ and output $A$ corresponds to input $100$ and output $B$ to input $50$) and the output for $25$ should be right in the middle between $B$ and $C$.

In summary: I'm given an array of values (the "given" outputs) consisting of at least two values. I'm also given an input value in the range $0 - 100$. The algorithm should output a single value corresponding to this input; which satisfies the description above.

Since my background in maths is very limited, I would prefer it if you could explain the mathematical symbols or name the variables something reminiscent of their function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first example given. If $75\%$ is right in the middle between $100\%$ and $50\%$. Why should it correspond to $0$ instead of $0.5$ (which is right in the middle between $1$ and $0$; the numbers corresponding to $100\%$ and $50\%$ respectively)?

Comment: If you have two values, they go at $100\%$ and $0\%$. If you have three values, they go at $100\%$, $50\%$, and $0\%$. If you have *four* values, they should go at $100\%$, $66.7\%$, $33.3\%$, and $0\%$, not at $100\%$, $75\%$, $50\%$, and $25\%$, shouldn't they?

Comment: WOW. What an improvement. Re-open vote well-deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your examples don't make sense assuming my interpretation of the problem.

In general, you have a sequence of $n \geq 2$ real numbers $(q_0, q_1,...,\, q_{n-1})$ and your interpolation parameter $t \in [0,1]$. You're only interested in the 2 values whose indices bookend $tn - t$. The interpolated value is: 
$$
(1 - \alpha) \,q_{\lfloor mt\rfloor}+\alpha \,q_{\lceil mt\rceil}
$$
where $m = n - 1$ and $\alpha = mt - \lfloor mt \rfloor$.

Looking at your 2nd example, you have $q = (0.5, 2, 1, 0, 1)$ with $n=5$ and $m=4$. Note that I've flipped your order as traditionally you progress left to right. At $t=0.125$ we have $mt = 4 \times 0.125 = 0.5$ and:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= 0.5 - \lfloor 0.5 \rfloor \\
&= 0.5 - 0 \\
&= 0.5
\end{align}
$$
which gives us
$$
(1-0.5) q_0 + 0.5q_1 = 1.25
$$
Which obviously doesn't equal 1, although it does yield 0 when $t=0.75
$.

EDIT: The question has changed since I provided this answer.

Comment: Could you please use a less math-heavy definition of what is going on?  I do not understand what you are saying at all.

Comment: You have a 2-step interpolation process. First, you have to find the 2 numeric values in your sequence to interpolate. So what we want is a way to take a percentage and see what index in the sequence it *would be*. If that index exists, then your value is just the value at that index. If it doesn't, then we find a value between the 2 that surround it.

There's nothing complicated, I show you the way to calculate it in the first equation of my post. Just take it one step at a time and feel free to ask for help when you're stuck at something specific.